# What is the relationship between http cache in browser and http status 304?

Tags: c#, browser-cache

In ASP.NET MVC, now we can response 304 code to browser, which means that the content in the server has not been changed, the browser can use its local cache for this url.

```
public ActionResult Image(int id){
   var image = _imageRepository.Get(id);
   if (image == null)
    throw new HttpException(404, "Image not found");
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"]))
   {
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    var lastMod = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"], "r",     provider).ToLocalTime();
    if (lastMod == image.TimeStamp.AddMilliseconds(-image.TimeStamp.Millisecond))
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 304;
        Response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
        return Content(String.Empty);
    }
   }
   var stream = new MemoryStream(image.GetImage());
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
   Response.Cache.SetLastModified(image.TimeStamp);
   return File(stream, image.MimeType);
 }
```

But I am a little confused about the logic in the browser. For example, when we first ask for a page http://www.test.com/index.html,it will load a javascript file aaa.js. But when the browser ask another page http://www.test.com/index2.html, this page also contains aaa.js.

Here comes the question. We know that the browser has a logic for http cache. I assume that when the browser asks for index2.html, it will check that it has aaa.js locally, which is available, so it will not communicate with server about this file. So here, no 304 is returned, because the browser has not request anything about this file.Is this the right logic?

Or every time it will communicate with the server to check the version of the file? In this situation, if we don't write any C# code to return 304 status, every time it will return the whole file.So I guess this is not the logic.

What is the relationship between the browser cache and 304 status?

Comment: There is a request and response for each of the page's linked assets, such as JS files and CSS files. So the browser will use the cached copy of `aaa.js` if there's a 304 response *for aaa.js*, regardless of what the response for `index.html` or `index2.html` is.

Comment: The question is, when the browser asks for index2.html, will it try to send a request to the server, or just use the local cache direclty? If it will send a request to the server, but we have not written any C# code to return 304, so it will return the whole aaa.js file again.

Comment: When you load index2.html, the browser will make a request to the server that includes an "if-modified-since" header. This metadata specifies how old the browser's cached copy of the page is. The server can use this to decide whether a fresh copy needs to be served (in which case you get a 200 response with the fresh content), or if the browser's cached copy will suffice (in which case a 304 is returned, and the browser will simply use its cached copy of the page). Note that this entire transaction has nothing to do with aaa.js yet, we're only talking about index2.html.

Comment: What I've described is **only** the sequence of events for loading index2.html, the HTML document. Once the browser has parsed the HTML, depending on what assets are linked, it may make more requests for JS files, CSS files and even more HTML files. A similar sequence of events will take place for each of those requests. Eg. once index2.html is loaded from the cache or from the server, the browser notices there's a script tag pointing to aaa.js. It will now make a request to the server for aaa.js, along with the same if-modified-since header I described earlier.

Comment: Hi Asad, thank you very much for your response. The browser has parsed the HTML for index2.html, and it notices there is a tag linked to aaa.js. As you said, So it will send a reques to the server to receive this file. But if in the server side, we have not written any code to check the "if-modified-since". The web application just simply return the aaa.js file. So here the browser will never use local cache in local?

Comment: That's correct. If you always return a status 200 with a fresh copy of `aaa.js`, the browser will always use that copy instead of the cache.

Comment: Note that this is not considering other caching heuristics such as the max-age header, that specifies how long the browser can implicitly trust its cache (without hitting the server at all).

Comment: OK. I think max-age header is exactly what I am concerning in this question. Is this set by the server in the response, or is it set by the browser? If we don't do anything about this property, how long time will it last for?

Comment: You set it as a header in the server response. If you decide to set it, I wouldn't advise setting it to a very long value, since updates to the cached copy of an asset on users' browsers are basically out of your hands until the next time max-age expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server response to the first request to `aaa.js` the browser may or may not request the file again the second time.

If no specific caching headers are sent by the server with the file, on the second page load the browser will send a request for `aaa.js` again. If the browser doesn't have the JS file in its cache, it will send the request the same as it did the first time. If `aaa.js` *is* in the browser cache it will send a request to the server containing an `If-Modified-Since` header with the date the file was previously downloaded. The server then checks if the file has been modified: if so it sends the new file; otherwise it sends the 304 header.

Now let's spool back to the beginning. In the initial request to `aaa.js` the server could include a `Cache-control` header telling the browser how long to cache the file for. Let's say `Cache-control: max-age=3600` which instructs to cache the file for one hour (3600 seconds).

If the user visits the second page within one hour, the browser *won't even send a request* to the server for `aaa.js`, it will just use the cached file without question.

Once the hour is up and a new page is loaded, the browser request `aaa.js` again.